# Multiple TransferSpreadsheet commands results in all created sheets being selected when opened

Tags: excel, ms-access

A bit hard to explain in words, but in this case the code and screenshot should really help.
I've created this piece of simple code to reproduce the issue. This code is created in a VBA module in Access 2013.

It creates two equal excels with 4 sheets, one in acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9 / xls format, the other in acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12XML / xlsx.

```
Function TestExportExcel()

s = "\xxx\Desktop\temp\test.xls"

        DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "tblPLCselect", s, , "sheet 1"
        DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "tblPLCselect", s, , "sheet 2"
        DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "tblPLCselect", s, , "sheet 3"
        DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "tblPLCselect", s, , "sheet 4"

s = "\xxx\Desktop\temp\test.xlsx"

        DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, , "tblPLCselect", s, , "sheet 1"
        DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, , "tblPLCselect", s, , "sheet 2"
        DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, , "tblPLCselect", s, , "sheet 3"
        DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, , "tblPLCselect", s, , "sheet 4"

End Function
```

The functional issue here is that in the second (xlsx) export all sheets are selected, in contradiction to the xls version:

[image]

I want only the first sheet to be selected when users open the sheet, but I also want to export in acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12XML / xlsx format.

Is there an efficiënt way (this export has to run very often) to manipulate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bizarre! Yes, I get same behavior. Only way I can see to fix is to use Excel automation.

```
Dim objExcel As Object, wb As Object
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set wb = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(s)
wb.Worksheets("sheet_2").Activate
wb.Worksheets("sheet_1").Activate
wb.Save
objExcel.Quit
```

Excel will replace space in sheet name with underscore character.

Comment: Thanks @june7. The only issue is the large number of exports that I have to do. Your suggested solution means opening, saving and closing each Excel. Which isn't very efficient. But I'm afraid this is the only way?

Comment: Yes, but the code accomplishes this automatically and user is not even aware it is happening. It is fast. As I said, I don't see any other way.

Comment: Correction, it's fast with my simple, small Excel file. A workbook with lots of data will likely slow performance.

Comment: I'll compare with benchmarks tomorrow to see how it performs, thanks!

Comment: PS. I added wb.Close SaveChanges:=True to avoid getting save prompts.

Comment: Interesting, I was not getting prompts with wb.Save. If answer does resolve issue, please mark accepted.

Comment: Off course, I just wanted to await the performance impact. And it doesn't seem to affect it much, so I can now mark this one as solved. Thanks for the help June7!